# Sqlalchemy get row in timeslot

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a model called Appointment which has the columns `datetime` which is a `DateTime` field and `duration` which is an `Integer` field and represents duration in minutes. Now I want to check if `func.now()` is between the `datetime` of the appointment and the sum of the `datetime` and `duration`

I am currently to try to do it this way, but I need a solution that will work for both PostgreSQL and SQLite.

```
current_appointment = Appointment.query.filter(
    Appointment.datetime.between(
        func.now(),
        func.timestampadd(
            'MINUTES', Appointment.duration, func.now()
            )
        )
    ).limit(1).one_or_none()
```

Comment: In your example don't you have your logic reversed? As in: is `Appointment.datetime` between *[now, now + duration]*. Also, is `TIMESTAMPADD` even a function in Postgresql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do this directly in the ORM for both sqlite and postgres, but sqlalchemy lets you extend it in a cross-dialect way with [Custom SQL Constructs and Compilation Extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html).

This snippet might not be exactly right because I hacked at it with some different models and translated it over for this, but I got something very close to render the postgres SQL correctly:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

class durationnow(expression.FunctionElement):
    type = DateTime()
    name = 'durationnow'

@compiles(durationnow, 'sqlite')
def sl_durationnow(element, compiler, **kw):
    return compiler.process(
        func.timestampadd('MINUTES', element.clauses, func.now())
    )

@compiles(durationnow, 'postgresql')
def pg_durationnow(element, compiler, **kw):
    return compiler.process(
        func.now() + func.make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, element.clauses)
    )

    # Or alternatively...
    # return "now() - make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {})".format(compiler.process(element.clauses))
    # which is more in-line with how the documentation uses 'compiles'
```

With something like that set up you should be able to turn your original query into a cross-dialect one that renders to SQL directly instead of doing the duration computation in Python:

```
current_appointment = Appointment.query.filter(
    Appointment.datetime.between(
        func.now(),
        durationnow(Appointment.duration)
    ).limit(1).one_or_none()
```

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer 1:** *First of all, think if it is not "cheaper" to actually use `postgresql` instead of sqlite everywhere. I assume you have development/production differences, which you should avoid. Installation of `postgresql` on any modern OS is quite trivial.*
Assuming above is not an option/desired, let's continue.

**Disclaimer 2:** The solution with the custom SQL construct (as per @Josh's answer) is really the only reasonable way to achieve this.
Unfortunately, the proposed solution does not actually work for `sqlite`, and could not be fixed with just few lines, hence a separate answer.

**Solution:**
Assuming you have the following model:

```
class Appointment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'appointment'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    datetime = Column(DateTime)  # @note: should be better named `start_date`?
    duration = Column(Integer)
```

`sqlite` is really tricky dealing with dates operations, especially adding/subtracting intervals from dates. Therefore, let's approach it somewhat differently and create custom functions to get an interval between two dates in minutes:

```
class diff_minutes(expression.FunctionElement):
    type = Integer()
    name = 'diff_minutes'

@compiles(diff_minutes, 'sqlite')
def sqlite_diff_minutes(element, compiler, **kw):
    dt1, dt2 = list(element.clauses)
    return compiler.process(
        (func.strftime('%s', dt1) - func.strftime('%s', dt2)) / 60
    )

@compiles(diff_minutes, 'postgresql')
def postgres_diff_minutes(element, compiler, **kw):
    dt1, dt2 = list(element.clauses)
    return compiler.process(func.extract('epoch', dt1 - dt2) / 60)
```

You can already implement your check using following query (*i am not adding `limit(1).one_or_none` in my examples, which you can obviously do when you need it*):

```
q = (
    session
    .query(Appointment)
    .filter(Appointment.datetime <= func.now())
    .filter(diff_minutes(func.now(), Appointment.datetime) <= Appointment.duration)
)
```

But now you are not limited by current time (`func.now()`), and you can check (and unit test) your data against any time:

```
# at_time = func.now()
at_time = datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 11, 17, 50, 0)
q = (
    session
    .query(Appointment)
    .filter(Appointment.datetime <= at_time)
    .filter(diff_minutes(at_time, Appointment.datetime) <= Appointment.duration)
)
```

Basically, **problem is solved here**, and the solution should work for both database engines you use.

**BONUS:**

You can *hide* the implementation of checking if the event is current using [Hybrid Methods](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/extensions/hybrid.html).

Lets add following to the `Appointment` class:

```
@hybrid_method
def is_current(self, at_time=None):
    if at_time is None:
        at_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    return self.datetime <= at_time <= self.datetime + datetime.timedelta(minutes=self.duration)

@is_current.expression
def is_current(cls, at_time=None):
    if at_time is None:
        at_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    stime = cls.datetime
    diffm = diff_minutes(at_time, cls.datetime)
    return and_(diffm >= 0, cls.duration >= diffm).label('is_current')
```

The first one allows you to run the check in memory (on python, not on SQL side):

```
print(my_appointment.is_current())
```

The second one allows you to construct query like below:

```
q = session.query(Appointment).filter(Appointment.is_current(at_time))
```

where if `at_time` it not specified, current time will be used. You can, of course then modify the query as you wish:

```
current_appointment = session.query(Appointment).filter(Appointment.is_current()).limit(1).one_or_none()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly...
Something like this?

```
def check_for_current_appt(appt_epoch, appt_duration):
    '''INPUT : appt_timestamp (int (epoch time)): start time for appointment
               appt_duration (int): duration of appointment in seconds
       OUTPUT : appt_underway (bool): True if appointment is currently underway'''

    now = time.time()
    appt_underway = 0 < (now - appt_epoch) < appt_duration
    return appt_underway
```

I'll leave it to you to convert to epoch time and seconds for the duration

Comment: I need this calculation to be in SQL, that's because I don't want to pull all of the appointments and itterate through it with python. That's just way too heavy

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of it, PostgreSQL uses unix timestamps while Sqlite uses iso-8601 timestamps stored as strings. So if you change the overall structure of your database to use the Sqlite format it should give you the functionality you want, you can convert datetime with the .isoformat() function. Unfortunately if you are not working with only test data you will have to iterate over all the rows to change them. Not sure if this is acceptable to you but is an easy way to do it.

Based on the datetime section of http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html